# jQuery autocomplete with remote json data

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var aToken = document.getElementById('aToken').value;

    jQuery("#name_inp").autocomplete("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token="+aToken, {
       width: 500,
       height: 200,
   max: 5000,
        dataType: 'json',
        cacheLength: 100,
       minChars: 1,
        parse: function (data) {
    alert(data);
            var rows = new Array();
           data = data.data;
       console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].name, result: data[i].name };
           }
             return rows;
         },
        formatItem: function (data, i, n, value, text, a, b, c, d) {
            var x = getImage(data.id);
             return "<div class='test2' onclick='return getId("+data.id+");'><span>" + data.name + "</span></div>";
       },

   }
     )
 });
```

The above code helps to fetch users friend list from remote graph api call.Can any one help to save the json data and search with user query and populate from the saved variable.

so that it will save time and populate result accurately.

thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is pretty explanatory :)

Hope it helps!

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var aToken = $('#aToken').val();

$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", {access_token: aToken}, function(result){

        var ppl = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++){
            ppl[i] = result.data[i].name;
        }

        $("#name_inp").autocomplete({
                                source: ppl,
                                width: 500,
                                height: 200,
                                max: 5000,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                cacheLength: 100,
                                minChars: 1
                            });
}, 'json');
});
```